# LaTeX Sublist Numbering

Tags: lists, enumerate, nesting

Here is what I want to do -

```
1. List 1
 1.1 sub list 1
 2.2 sub list 2
2. List 2
 2.1 sub list 1
```

I tried doing this,

```
\begin{enumerate}    
  \item List 1

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item sub list 1
    \item sub list 2
  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
```

But this gives me -

```
1. List 1
 a. sub list 1
 b. sub list 2
```

How should I go about this.

Do I have to do...

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=2.\arabic*.]
\item Sub list
\end{enumerate}
```

for every sublist and number manually?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package and its `label*` key-value option which appends it value to the parent label.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label*=\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}    
  \item List 1

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item sub list 1
    \item sub list 2

    \begin{enumerate}
      \item subsub list 1
    \end{enumerate}

  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]